# Huge amount of reputation gained

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a very simple question, and for whatever reason, I was notified of my reputation gain, which was ridiculously high:
[image]

I believe that I read somewhere that if you get above a certain reputation, you are automatically granted reputation on other sites. However, as you see in this picture, I was also awarded rep on SO as well as the others:
[image]

Not that I'm against getting reputation, I just wondered if this was normal.

Comment: Does seem kinda odd that you gained 100 on SO when SO seems to be the one that pushed you over the 200 mark

Comment: That was my thought.

Comment: This is by design, you got the association bonus of 100 rep on all sites that you joined because you crossed 200 rep on one of them. That includes SO.

Comment: @rene Does that mean that you basically cannot have a reputation between 200 and 300, because you are automatically bumped up once you hit 200?

Comment: @CacheStaheli Well, it is possible to lose reputation and fall back between 200 and 300. The bonus is not revoked.

Comment: If you don't have joined other sites there is no bonus ...

Comment: @CacheStaheli No, you're restricted to a max of 200 per site.

Comment: I didn't get a +100 on so when i crossed 200 rep, but that was a long time ago